# Minecraft bufferedImage write

Tags: java, image, minecraft

Update: I found where it writes the image file, and it writes it in the "eclipse" folder of the mod instead of the "bin" folder which is where I want it to write to. Any ideas? (eclipse and bin are both subfolders of the main folder for the mod, so I cannot access bin from eclipse unless I am able to go backwards in the file hierarchy)

THE FOLLOWING UPDATE IS THE ONLY PROBLEM THAT NEEDS FIXING, THE REST IS NOW (while mildly helpful if answered) IRRELEVANT

Update: After realizing that I could simply use this to create the item textures, then move them to the appropriate folder I attempted to do so, only to discover that the pixels I set to be printed were in fact printed in white rather than "color1" which should have been a dark green NOTE: I have tried it without the class "color1" variable in case that is the thing causing problems, and it still printed it in white only

So... I'm not entirely sure if it is relevant that I am doing this as part of a minecraft mod or if I am simply doing it wrong in general. You probably won't need to know what minecraft is to fix this, but I may be wrong about that. anyway, so my problem is that I would like to create an image in java then save it as a .png file which I can then use for minecraft textures so that if I want to make a new tool/armor set or something I would merely have to give it the 5 base colors or whatever it is along with the material name and it will make the 9 or so items associated with that material, possibly automatically making 4 more if it is metallic in which case the same textures merely with different color schemes are used.

Here is the code:

```
package minecraftmage113.magecore.items;

import net.minecraft.item.Item;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;

import javax.imageio.*;

public class ItemIngot extends Item {
    private String name;
    private Item item;
    private Color color1;
    private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage new BufferedImage(16, 16, 2);
    public ItemIngot(String name, Item item){
        this.name=name;
        this.item=item;
    }
    public ItemIngot(String name, Color color1){
        image.getGraphics().setColor(color1);
        image.getGraphics().drawRect(10, 2, 1, 0);
        image.getGraphics().drawRect(7, 3, 2, 0);
        image.getGraphics().drawRect(12, 3, 0, 0);
        File outputfile = new File("mc:ItemIngot"+name+".png");
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
            System.out.println("ItemIngotBronze successfully created");
        }
        try {
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);
            for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
                System.out.println("ItemIngotBronze successfully saved");
            } 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public Item getItem(){
        return item;
    } 
    public void setItem(Item item){
        this.item = item;
    }

}
```

So... there. The idea is that this class will create a new 16x16 texture when an object is created, the texture should have... 6 pixels filled in, and they should be the color provided in the second constructor.

I am indeed using the correct constructor as I get the 50 lines or whatever I set it to of attention getter about how the thing should have been written to a file.

The problem is that the new file doesn't appear. I expect I am just doing something foolish regarding the write function, but it could be something else.